# ReactiveX emit null or sentinel value after timeout

Tags: rx-java, reactivex

Looking for a clean way to transform a source `Observable` to emit a single `null` (or sentinel value) after not emitting an item for some duration.

For example, if the source observable emits `1, 2, 3` then stops emitting for 10 seconds before emitting `4, 5, 6` I would like the emitted items to be `1, 2, 3, null, 4, 5, 6`.

The use case is for displaying values in a UI where the displayed value should turn into a dash `-` or `N/A` if the last emitted value is stale/old.

I looked into the `timeout` operator but it terminates the `Observable` when the timeout occurs which is undesirable.

Using RxJava.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [akarnokd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35873635/1267663) and [an answer in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23395057/1267663), an alternative implementation:

#### A single sentinel value (as per the OP)

If you're looking for a single value to indicate the lapse of time between emissions:

```java
final TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
final TestSubject<Integer> subject = TestSubject.create(scheduler);
final TestSubscriber<Integer> subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();

final long duration = 100;
final Observable<Integer> timeout = Observable.just(-1).delay(duration, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler)
    .concatWith(Observable.never())
    .takeUntil(subject)
    .repeat();

subject.mergeWith(timeout).subscribe(subscriber);

subject.onNext(1,   0);
subject.onNext(2, 100);
subject.onNext(3, 200);

scheduler.advanceTimeBy(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
scheduler.advanceTimeBy(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

subject.onNext(4,   0);
subject.onNext(5, 100);
subject.onNext(6, 200);

scheduler.advanceTimeBy(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

subscriber.assertNoTerminalEvent();
subscriber.assertReceivedOnNext(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, -1, 4, 5, 6));
```

#### Continuous sentinel values

If you're looking to receive values continuously after the source observable not emitting for some duration:

```java
final TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
final TestSubject<Integer> subject = TestSubject.create(scheduler);
final TestSubscriber<Integer> subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();

final long duration = 100;
final Observable<Integer> timeout = Observable.interval(duration, duration, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler)
    .map(x -> -1)
    .takeUntil(subject)
    .repeat();

subject.mergeWith(timeout).subscribe(subscriber);

subject.onNext(1,   0);
subject.onNext(2, 100);
subject.onNext(3, 200);

scheduler.advanceTimeBy(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
scheduler.advanceTimeBy(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

subject.onNext(4,   0);
subject.onNext(5, 100);
subject.onNext(6, 200);

scheduler.advanceTimeBy(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

subscriber.assertNoTerminalEvent();
subscriber.assertReceivedOnNext(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, -1, -1, -1, 4, 5, 6));
```

---

The difference being the `timeout` observable and whether it's recurring or not.

You can replace `-1` with `null` as needed.

All of the above is tested with RxJava 1.0.17 using Java `1.8.0_72`.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with a somewhat complicated publish-amb-timer setup:

```
PublishSubject<Integer> ps = PublishSubject.create();
TestScheduler s = Schedulers.test();
TestSubscriber<Integer> ts = new TestSubscriber<>();

ps.publish(o -> 
    o.take(1).ambWith(Observable.timer(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, s).map(v -> (Integer)null))
    .repeat().takeUntil(o.ignoreElements())
).subscribe(ts);

ps.onNext(1);
ps.onNext(2);
ps.onNext(3);

s.advanceTimeBy(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

ps.onNext(4);
ps.onNext(5);
ps.onNext(6);
ps.onCompleted();

ts.assertValues(1, 2, 3, null, 4, 5, 6);
```

What happens is that the source is published so you can take items one by one from it or a timer event, make sure the fastest one wins and repeat it with the next value, all without resubscribing to the original source all the time.

**Edit** fixed the case when the upstream completes the repeat() goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks, this sheds some light on the problem. What is the purpose of calling `ps.publish` to create a `ConnectableObserver`? My understanding is that `ConnectableObserver` requires its `connect()` method to be called in order to emit items which isn't shown in your example code.