# Continue subscribing for data even after exception using rx notifications

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

In the below code the subscriber stops recieving data whenever there is a timeout exception. How can I make sure that the subscriber does not stop when there is exception.

```
public class ReactiveDataService
{
    private static String[] quotes = {"ITEM1", "ITEM2", "ITEM3"};
    public Observable<Notification<String>> getStreamData()
    {

    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        if(!subscriber.isUnsubscribed())
        {

            Stream<String> streams = Arrays.stream(quotes);
            streams.map(quote -> quote.toString()).filter(quote -> quote!=null)
            .forEach(q -> { 
                subscriber.onNext(Notification.createOnNext(q));
                try
                {
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    Integer i = (rand.nextInt(5)+1)*1000;
                    Thread.sleep(i);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    });

    }
}    


public class ReactiveResource
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Observable<Notification<String>> watcher = new ReactiveResource().getData()
    .timeout(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .doOnError(failure -> System.out.println("Error:" + failure.getCause()))
    .onErrorResumeNext(th -> {
        return Observable.just(Notification.createOnError(new TimeoutException("Timed Out!")));
    });

    watcher.subscribe(
            ReactiveResource::callBack, 
            ReactiveResource::errorCallBack,
            ReactiveResource::completeCallBack
    );
}

public static Action1 callBack(Notification<String> data)
{
    System.out.println(data.getValue());
    return null;
}

public static void errorCallBack(Throwable throwable)
{
    System.out.println(throwable instanceof TimeoutException);
    System.out.println(throwable);      
}

public static void completeCallBack()
{
    System.out.println("On completed successfully");
}


private Observable<Notification<String>> getData()
{
    return new ReactiveDataService().getStreamData();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps don't timeout? It is logically exclusive: you either stop the sequence due to lack of data or you keep waiting. You didn't explain the original requirements, but there was a [question some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35873635/61158) where the developer wanted to insert a keep-alive item after while there was no data in a periodic fashion.

Comment: It was me who asked the previous question. I want to keep waiting and also raise an event when I don't get data for specified amount of time.

Comment: Then the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35873635/61158) answer should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `publish`, `mergeWith` and `timer` to achieve this effect:

```
static <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> onTimeoutKeepAlive(
        long timeout, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler, T keepAliveItem) {
    return upstream -> 
        upstream.publish(o ->
            o.mergeWith(
                Observable.timer(timeout, unit, scheduler)
                .map(t -> keepAliveItem)
                .takeUntil(o)
                .repeat()
                .takeUntil(o.ignoreElements().toObservable())
            )
        );
}
```

usage:

```
source
    .compose(onTimeoutKeepAlive(
         10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.computation(),
         Notification.createOnError(new TimeoutException())
    ))
    .subscribe(/* ... */);
```