# RxJava: insert additional emission if source is too slow

Tags: rx-java

I have a RxJava v1.x Observable (a Subject actually) which under normal circumstances will emit elements once per second. Sometimes there may be interruptions causing emissions to stop for a while (without signaling an error or completing!), until they pick up again at the normal rate.

I am looking a way to turn this source Observable into another one which mirrors each source emission but "inserts" a special "placeholder element" if the source stays silent for too long (e.g. more than 30s), without unsubscribing from the source (i.e. it should still mirror subsequent source emissions)!

I'll try to illustrate the situation:

```
source:
s[t=1], s[t=2], s[t=3], s[t=40], s[t=41], ...

result:
s[t=1], s[t=2], s[t=3], x[t=33], s[t=40], s[t=41], ...
```

Here, `x` is the "inserted" element emitted after the source stayed silent for 30 seconds (i.e. at time t=33).

Ideally I want to achieve this without ever having to stop or restart the source.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35873244/61158

Comment: Would you want multiple placeholders? So if the source is silent for 80 seconds, would you want to see two placeholders?

Comment: I'm not sure about RxJava, but in C# you can do it like this: `source.Select(x => Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0)).Select(y => -1L).StartWith(x)).Switch()`

Comment: @Shlomo a single placeholder would be enough

Comment: @Matthias - Then `source.Select(x => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0)).Select(y => -1L).StartWith(x)).Switch()` would do in C#.

Comment: Any idea what the RxJava equivalent of `Switch()` could be?

Comment: According to [this](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/switch.html) `switchOnNext`